# Installation of Ubuntu Server Edition on HP Proliant DL360 G3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware

I want to buy a HP Proliant DL360 G3 server, but I have heard there are some problems with installation of Ubuntu Server Edition on such a server.

Is that true and is there any way to fix the problems?

You are also very welcome to recommend a better open source OS for such a server.

Yours sincerely

Jonathan Frank

Comment: Unless you are researching it for archeological purposes I wouldn't bother. Even if you're broke you should be able to get a G4 or G5 for next to nothing.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/hp

Comment: +1, but these are only "certified good" models.  This is what is essentially supported, but others will work.

Answer (score 1):

G3 is almost 4 generations old, as HP is just now releasing G7s.

Since it is so old, I take it you are buying it second hand. Which means you can't get a loaner with which to test.

The big issue I have had with most vendor hardware is making sure the OS has the correct RAID/array controller driver. This is more of an issue with trying to get old Operating Systems to run on new hardware.

Linux in general has good support of running newer OSs on older hardware.

HP has just started to make Ubuntu tools available for their servers.

Here is the list of supported operating systems for an HP dl360 G3
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3288138&lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=316558&taskId=135

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the DL360 G3, but I have a DL380 G2 on which I was able to install Ubuntu Server 8.04 seamlessly.  They both use the Smart Array 5i RAID Controller, and everything else is pretty standard hardware.  (The iLO is the Out-of-band management, so it doesn't really interact with the OS.)

**UPDATE**:  Oddly enough, I just received pair of DL360 G3's myself.  (At worst, one will be parts.)  I'll let you know how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the latest version of Ubuntu SE on DL380 G3 just yesterday. I'd go with it on 360 as well. I didn't experience any issues during the installation process and managed to install majority of the HP support software as well (via deb packages).